# I only know how to read file using fscanf, but I have to use scanf and input redirection to do it. I don't think I am allowed to do fgets

Tags: arrays, c, file, redirect

I have a input file which has 1500 data. But I have include a file data which has 25 data(for example). I have finished the program using fscanf but I need to use scanf and input redirection to read the file then doing some calculation. I have no idea how to do it. I also need to read the file until EOF.

this is what I did with fscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_data(int max)
{

    printf("The number is %d\n", max);
}
double mean (double *x, int n)
{
    double total = 0;
double store = 0 ; 
    for (int i=0 ; i < n; ++i)
    {
        total = store + x[i];
        store=total ;

    }
   double mean2 = (total/n);
    return mean2;
}
int main()
{

    FILE *obk ;
    double arr[MAXIMUM], arr1[MAXIMUM], arr2[MAXIMUM];
    obk = fopen ( "in.txt", "r");

    if (obk == NULL )
    {
        printf(" There is no sucha file");
    }
    int j = 0;
    while(fscanf(obk, "%lf", &arr[j])!=EOF)

    {
        j++;
        count++;
        printf("%d\n",arr[j]);

    }
    read_data( arr,  count);


    double mean1 = mean(arr, count);
    printf("%lf", mean1);
}
```

in.text

```
12
23
23
4
54
66
55
44
3
23
67
88
```

Comment: Looks semi-okay. What's the issue? If it doesn't work, try: `while(fscanf(obk, "%lf", &arr[j])==1)` But, compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`). This: `printf("%d\n",arr[j]);` would be flagged by the compiler. `arr` is a `double` array, so you can't use `%d`. You want: `printf("%g\n",arr[j]);`

Comment: I cant used fscanf. I was assigned to use scanf and input redirection. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You have a bug with the `printf` as I've described. Fix that. You can't use `fscanf`? That's a stupid instructor, IMO. And, you may tell s/he that a C programmer with 50+ years experience said so. Instead of using `fopen` and `fscanf` [the sensible way]. Remove the `fopen`. Change `fscanf(obk,...)` into `scanf(...)`. But, invoke your program with (e.g.) `./myprogram < in.txt`

Comment: He just dont want us to use it for now

Answer (score 0):

Your request can resolved as `./test < in.txt` i.e. redirection sends the contents of the input file to stdin, so you need to read from stdin inside your code.

Example code to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXIMUM 256

int read_data(int max)
{
    printf("The number is %d\n", max);
}

double mean (double *x, int n)
{
    double total = 0;
    double store = 0 ;
    for (int i=0 ; i < n; ++i)
    {
        total = store + x[i];
        store=total ;

    }
   double mean2 = (total/n);
    return mean2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double arr[MAXIMUM], arr1[MAXIMUM], arr2[MAXIMUM];
    
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;

    double d;
    while (scanf("%lf", &d)!= EOF)
    {
        j++;
        count++;
        arr[j] = d;
        printf("%lf\n",arr[j]);
    }
    read_data( count);

    double mean1 = mean(arr, count);
    printf("%lf", mean1);
    return 0;
}
```

Run.

```
 ./test < in.txt
```

Comment: @Obiick Nice to help :)